# How to update specific column in vb.net 2013 SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, textbox

I have 4 tables: `Code_Product, Name_Product, Color_Product, Size_Product`

And code:

```
 Public Sub ExecuteQuery(query As String)
       Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
      command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_Product SET Name_Product = '" & txtNameProduct.Text & "' , Color_Product = '" & txtColorProduct.Text & "', Size_Product = '" & txtSizeProduct.Text & "' where Kode_Produk= '" & txtKodeProduk.Text & "'"

ExecuteQuery(updateQuery)

MessageBox.Show("Data has been changed")
```

Notes: the code work.

But, the code changes all columns, and I just want to change only one column. How?

Comment: Because you are specifically telling to update those other fields. Exclude the columns you dont need to update. Also you didnt mention what column you only wanted changed. On another note use parameters and wrap your connections and commands in using statements, you need to dispose of them...

Comment: Also revise your code so that you use SQL Parameters

Comment: revise SQL Parameter like what?

Answer (score -1):

replace this line

```
Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_Product SET Name_Product = '" & txtNameProduct.Text & "' , Color_Product = '" & txtColorProduct.Text & "', Size_Product = '" & txtSizeProduct.Text & "' where Kode_Produk= '" & txtKodeProduk.Text & "'"
```

with this. Pass only that column which you want to update.

```
Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE tbl_Product SET Name_Product = '" & txtNameProduct.Text & "'  where Kode_Produk= '" & txtKodeProduk.Text & "'"
```

Comment: i have tried like that before. But, it only change column Name_Product.
I mean, one column, but the code can cover all possibilities change in any one column. not only column Name_Product.

Comment: debug your code and tell me the value of updateQuery(final query)

Comment: the value?
ref to your code, it's change Name_Product, with new value, and clear another column.
It should change Name_Product or another one column, but the column that won't be updated still keep the old data.